# Rails - How to validate radio button and text field values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, radio-button

I'm surprised that no one asked this question yet. I am trying to validate radio buttons, with values and then a custom button, in a form, where users can type in custom amounts.

Here is my form

```
<%= f.radio_button(:price, 100)
<%= f.label(:price, "$100"</br>
<%= f.radio_button(:price, 200)
<%= f.label(:price, "$200"</br>
<%= f.radio_button(:price, 300)
<%= f.label(:price, "$300"</br>
<%= f.radio_button(:price, :price)
<%= f.label(:price, "Custom:"</br>
<%= f.text_field(:price) %>
```

The form will look like this

O $100

O $200

O $300

O Custom _________________

Anyways, I wrote this validation method in my model

```
validates :price, inclusion: { in: [*100..1000] }
```

The datatype of `:price` is a decimal.

The form validates, when I type in text_field values, but not when I click on a radio button. Am I missing something? `validates_inclusion` should validate whether a value is in a range. All 3 radio button values (100, 200, 300) are in the range 100..1000. I do not understand why this doesn't work.

When I submit the values from the radio buttons, the parameter is not being saved. It is saved when I submit values from the text field though.

Here is a similar question

[Rails 4 radio button form helper, true not validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119254/rails-4-radio-button-form-helper-true-not-validating)

They said to use `inclusion`, but I had already tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: something else is wrong, I set this up exactly the same without issue.  In your create action on your controller can you try `@object.valid?` then give me the output of `@object.errors`

Comment: `[*100..1000]` is an array of 901 elements. A simple range [should suffice](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb). Don't waste memory, you might need it later :)

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried running this in console. I set `g = Object.new` to create a new instance of my object. I then typed `g.valid?`and got false. `g.errors.full_messages` returned "Amount is not included in the list". For now, I'm going to try skipping that validation, saving an object, and using rails console to get info.

Comment: Alright, when I bring up my new object in `rails console`, I see that the value for `amount` is nil. `g.valid?' returns true, but `g.amount.nil?` also returns true

Comment: Is the problem that the parameter is a string, and you're testing it against a range of integers?

Comment: In `schema.rb`, the amount is listed as type `decimal`

Comment: This is unrelated, but I would highly recommend you saving money in pennies as an integer. It cleans up a lot of logic later when you need to do math or convert to other currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this, but you should be using integer to store price, not decimal. Use this method t convert either decimal, integer, or string values to be saved in your DB as pennies.

```
def price=(val)
  val.gsub!(',', '') if val.kind_of? String
  if !!(val =~ /\.+/)
    write_attribute(:price, (val.to_f * 100).to_i)
  elsif val.to_i.to_s == val
    write_attribute(:price, val.to_i)
  else
    write_attribute(:price, val)
  end
end
```

You then should be able to do this:

```
validates :price,   numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 100, 
                                    less_than_or_equal_to: 1000,
                                    message: 'not a valid price' }
```

Source: I have this code working for me in a project right now.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried with `numericality` validator?

```
validates :price,
    numericality: {
        greater_than_or_equal_to: 100,
        less_than_or_equal_to: 1000,
        only_integer: true # or false to accept decimals
    }
```

Comment: I just tried that and it said "amount" is not a number. It looks like the radio button values are not getting saved.

Comment: I think the numbers need to be floats for this to work with a decimal value. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it turns out that there is no way to do this. I tested it out, by removing the `text-field` tag and selecting only radio buttons. The values were then saved. Adding the text field back, the values were "nil" when selecting radio buttons, because the field for `amount` was empty.

The reason was I had two separate fields for the `:amount` attribute. There was one way to solve this though.

```
rails g migration AddCustomToProducts custom_amount:string     # Need to create a separate field
rake db:migrate                                                # Migrate database
```

You could then set up your fields as follows

```
<%= f.radio_button(:price, 100)
<%= f.label(:price, "$100"</br>

<%= f.radio_button(:price, 200)
<%= f.label(:price, "$200"</br>

<%= f.radio_button(:price, 300)
<%= f.label(:price, "$300"</br>

<%= f.label(:custom_price, "Custom:"</br>
<%= f.text_field(:custom_price) %>
```

With this, I solved my problem.